# how to get a string value from java list

Tags: java, arrays, spring-mvc

I want to select one of the list. List contains **five values.**I want to find one values from list. I want to do something when the list has **importer**. I gave my cord I created a list calld **roleosuser**. How to check roleosuser list has importer.when it has importer i want to do something..How can i do that

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/view/all/posted-applications/importer")
public String viewallApplicationofIMPORTER(Model model) {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    long userId = 0;
    List <String> roleosuser;
    if (principal != null && principal instanceof AuthenticatedUser) {
        AuthenticatedUser auth = (AuthenticatedUser) principal;
        userId = auth.getUserId();
        roleosuser= auth.getUserRoles();

        if(roleosuser.get(0)) {
            System.out.println("importer equals "+roleosuser);
        }
        model.addAttribute("userID", userId);
    }
    return "applicationManageIMPORTER";
}
```

I want to get "IMPORTER" value from my list. `List` has importer and agent values. How to do this?

Comment: question is not quite clear. Describe more in generic ideas.

Comment: `if (roleosuser.contains("IMPORTER")) { ... }`

Comment: Your question seems unclear...from what I get..you want one value from the list..you need a for loop and you can get the "importer" value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 if(roleosuser.contains("IMPORTER")) {
         System.out.println("found");
         // do whatever you want
     }
```

or

if you want to know the index you can use this

```
roleosuser.indexOf("IMPORTER")
```